# How PHP handles cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying the following but it doesn't work...

Make a cookie. Launch a php script. The script will shows the cookie's content after 10 seconds. While the scripts runs, delete the cookie. Why the script shows cookie's data, like the cookie still exists?

```
<?php
    sleep(10000);
    echo $_COOKIE['data'];
?>
```

To make and delete the make the cookies I used the chrome extension "Edit This Cookie"

Comment: I am not asking for code, I just want to understand why this doesn't work. I tried what i explain above.

Comment: Why not reading the docs or one of the 100s of tutorials ? There are some excellent ones out there.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are sent from the browser to the server as part of the HTTP request for the page, and then PHP puts them into the `$_COOKIE` array. That happens just before the start of the script.

Using `$_COOKIE` does not access the client's computer to get the current cookies in real time. During the script, any changes to the cookies are invisible. You won't be able to detect those changes until the *next* request for the page, when the browser will send the cookies again.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem isn't related to how PHP handles cookies, but rather your understanding of how cookies work. (Without seeing your code, this is however *complete and utter speculation*.)

Getting to the point, cookies are only set/read when content is sent/received from the browser, as the cookie data is transmitted a part of the HTTP headers, which only occur on page load. As such, you'll need to reload the page (rather than simply waiting 'x' seconds) to be able to see any changes you've made.

In terms of some specifics:

1. When you set a cookie, this will be sent to the browser (and subsequently stored accordingly) in the outbound HTTP response from the web server.
2. To read a cookie, it must have been previously set as above in which case it'll be presented to the web server as a part of subsequent browse URI requests
3. Deleting a cookie follows the same rules as setting, so the cookie will only cease to be available on subsequent requests from the browser.

Incidentally, you can trivially confirm the above using [INSERT YOUR BROWSER OF CHOICE HERE]'s developer tools - simply view the request/response headers and you'll see the cookie data.